# How can I disable some item in python Enum, but not remove them

Tags: python, filter, enums, items

I have a enum `OsTypeEnum`:

```
class OsTypeEnum(Enum):
    WINDOWS = 100
    LINUX = 200
    MAC = 300
    ANDROID = 400
    IOS = 500

    @classmethod
    def get_list(cls):
        ret = []
        for e in cls:
           ret.append({'name': e.name, 'value': e.value})
        return ret
```

I need to hide `ANDROID` and `IOS` from calling the `get_list` function， but don't want to remove them from the `OsTypeEnum`.

Comment: `if e.value < 400: ret.append(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than hard-code the list of members to exclude, I would make that information part of each member instead.  I'll show code using the [`aenum`](https://pypi.org/project/aenum/) library<sup>1</sup>, but it can be done using the stdlib version, just more verbosely.

```
from aenum import Enum

class OsTypeEnum(Enum):
    #
    _init_ = 'value type'
    #
    WINDOWS = 100, 'pc'
    LINUX = 200, 'pc'
    MAC = 300, 'pc'
    ANDROID = 400, 'mobile'
    IOS = 500, 'mobile'
    #
    @classmethod
    def get_pc_list(cls):
        ret = []
        for e in cls:
            if e.type == 'pc':
                ret.append({'name': e.name, 'value': e.value})
        return ret
    #
    @classmethod
    def get_mobile_list(cls):
        ret = []
        for e in cls:
            if e.type == 'mobile':
                ret.append({'name': e.name, 'value': e.value})
        return ret
```

By storing that extra piece of information on the member, you are more easily able to get your original list, plus other lists.

In use, it looks like:

```
>>> OsTypeEnum.get_pc_list()
[{'name': 'WINDOWS', 'value': 100}, {'name': 'LINUX', 'value': 200}, {'name': 'MAC', 'value': 300}]

>>> OsTypeEnum.get_mobile_list()
[{'name': 'ANDROID', 'value': 400}, {'name': 'IOS', 'value': 500}]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Your answer is awesome. I will use the aenum to refactor my code using namedtuple. It's more readable.

Comment: @Jackeroo:  Be aware that if you use a `namedtuple` then the value of the member will be, e.g., `(100, "pc")` and not `100`

Comment: Thanks.  **namedtuple** may be a little annoying to access the 'code', So I will refactor the code using aenum.

Answer (score 3):

You can create excluded enums list

```
class OsTypeEnum(Enum):
    WINDOWS = 100
    LINUX = 200
    MAC = 300
    ANDROID = 400
    IOS = 500

    @classmethod
    def get_list(cls):
        ret = []
        for e in cls:
            if e not in cls.__get_excluded():
                ret.append({'name': e.name, 'value': e.value})
        return ret

    @classmethod
    def __get_excluded(cls):
        return [cls.ANDROID, cls.IOS]
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a good candidate for an `if` statement. `if` the enum is not `ANDROID` or `IOS`, then add it to the return value.